# How to use the verbose name of a language choice in Django-Countries with Django Filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter, django-countries

I have this Django Filter:

```py
from django_countries.data import COUNTRIES

owner__nationality = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=COUNTRIES, widget=Select2MultipleWidget)
```

So I guessed I just use the original choices field to filter on nationality (for which I used `Django Countries` to fill the data)
As you can see in the source code here, the import is correct: 
https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries/blob/master/django_countries/data.py

However on the front end the dropdown looks like this:

[image]

How can I get full countries to be displayed there? I also don't quite understand why there is only one letter there. Can somebody clarify?

By the way I know about get_FOO_display()

Comment: you just need to add in models.py **`    Country                 = CountryField(blank_label='Select Country')
`** why you want select multiple country

Comment: I try to pull the hard-coded choice data, so I can use it with `Django-Filter` Not the `CountryField`.

Comment: The models are already declared and populated with the `CountryField`. Right now I try to get the choice data so I can run it against a Queryset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MultipleChoiceFilter` takes iterable of tuples as as choices. Package you mentioned provides `COUNTRIES` as dictionary. Try doing

```
from django_countries.data import COUNTRIES

owner__nationality = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(
    choices=[(k, v) for k, v in COUNTRIES.items()],
    widget=Select2MultipleWidget
)
```